# SmoothStreaming issues on Chromecast

Tags: google-cast, chromecast, smooth-streaming

I'm trying to load a smoothstreaming media into the chromecast. For that I've used the samples provided by google:

```
<body>
<video id='vid' />
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="//www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/receiver/2.0.0/cast_receiver.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="//www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/mediaplayer/0.3.0/media_player.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
// If you set ?Debug=true in the URL, such as a different App ID in the
// developer console, include debugging information.
    cast.receiver.logger.setLevelValue(cast.receiver.LoggerLevel.DEBUG);

  var mediaElement = document.getElementById('vid');

// Create the media manager. This will handle all media messages by default.
  window.mediaManager = new cast.receiver.MediaManager(mediaElement);

// Remember the default value for the Receiver onLoad, so this sample can Play
// non-adaptive media as well.
  window.defaultOnLoad = mediaManager.onLoad;
  mediaManager.onLoad = function (event) {
/proto

// MPEG-DASH
        protocol = cast.player.api.CreateDashStreamingProtocol(host);
      } else if (url.indexOf('.ism/') >= 0) {
// Smooth Streaming
        protocol = cast.player.api.CreateSmoothStreamingProtocol(host);
      }
// How to override a method in Host. I know that it's safe to just provide this
// method.
      host.onError = function(errorCode) {
        console.log("Fatal Error - "+errorCode);
        window.player.unload();
      };
// If you need cookies, then set withCredentials = true also set any header
// information you need.  If you don't need them, there can be some unexpected
// effects by setting this value.
//      host.updateSegmentRequestInfo = function(requestInfo) {
//        requestInfo.withCredentials = true;
//      };
      console.log("we have protocol "+ext);
      if (protocol !== null) {
        console.log("Starting Media Player Library");
        window.player = new cast.player.api.Player(host);
        window.player.load(protocol, initStart);
      }
      mediaElement.autoplay = autoplay;  // Make sure autoplay get's set
      if (url.lastIndexOf('.m3u8') >= 0) {
// HTTP Live Streaming
        protocol = cast.player.api.CreateHlsStreamingProtocol(host);
      } else if (url.lastIndexOf('.mpd') >= 0) {
// MPEG-DASH
        protocol = cast.player.api.CreateDashStreamingProtocol(host);
      } else if (url.indexOf('.ism/') >= 0) {
// Smooth Streaming
        protocol = cast.player.api.CreateSmoothStreamingProtocol(host);
      }
// How to override a method in Host. I know that it's safe to just provide this
// method.
      host.onError = function(errorCode) {
        console.log("Fatal Error - "+errorCode);
        window.player.unload();
      };
// If you need cookies, then set withCredentials = true also set any header
// information you need.  If you don't need them, there can be some unexpected
// effects by setting this value.
//      host.updateSegmentRequestInfo = function(requestInfo) {
//        requestInfo.withCredentials = true;
//      };
      console.log("we have protocol "+ext);
```

And on the sender:

```
/**
 * global variables
 */
var currentMediaSession = null;
var currentVolume = 0.5;
var progressFlag = 1;
var mediaCurrentTime = 0;
var session = null;
var mediaURLs = [
           'http://playready.directtaps.net/smoothstreaming/TTLSS720VC1/To_The_Limit_720.ism/',
           'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/ED_1280.mp4',
           'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/tears_of_steel_1080p.mov',
           'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/reel_2012_1280x720.mp4',
           'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/Google%20IO%202011%2045%20Min%20Walk%20Out.mp3'];
var mediaTitles = [
           'Big Buck Bunny',
           'Elephant Dream',
           'Tears of Steel',
           'Reel 2012',
           'Google I/O 2011 Audio'];

var mediaThumbs = [
           'images/bunny.jpg',
           'images/ed.jpg',
           'images/Tears.jpg',
           'images/reel.jpg',
           'images/google-io-2011.jpg'];
var currentMediaURL = mediaURLs[0];


/**
 * Call initialization
 */
if (!chrome.cast || !chrome.cast.isAvailable) {
  setTimeout(initializeCastApi, 1000);
}

/**
 * initialization
 */
function initializeCastApi() {
  // default app ID to the default media receiver app
  // optional: you may change it to your own app ID/receiver
  var applicationID = '21176C05';
  var sessionRequest = new chrome.cast.SessionRequest(applicationID);
  var apiConfig = new chrome.cast.ApiConfig(sessionRequest,
    sessionListener,
    receiverListener);

  chrome.cast.initialize(apiConfig, onInitSuccess, onError);
};

/**
 * initialization success callback
 */
function onInitSuccess() {
  appendMessage("init success");
}

/**
 * initialization error callback
 */
function onError() {
  console.log("error");
  appendMessage("error");
}

/**
 * generic success callback
 */
function onSuccess(message) {
  console.log(message);
}

/**
 * callback on success for stopping app
 */
function onStopAppSuccess() {
  console.log('Session stopped');
  appendMessage('Session stopped');
  document.getElementById("casticon").src = 'images/cast_icon_idle.png'; 
}

/**
 * session listener during initialization
 */
function sessionListener(e) {
  console.log('New session ID: ' + e.sessionId);
  appendMessage('New session ID:' + e.sessionId);
  session = e;
  if (session.media.length != 0) {
    appendMessage(
        'Found ' + session.media.length + ' existing media sessions.');
    onMediaDiscovered('onRequestSessionSuccess_', session.media[0]);
  }
  session.addMediaListener(
      onMediaDiscovered.bind(this, 'addMediaListener'));
  session.addUpdateListener(sessionUpdateListener.bind(this));  
}

/**
 * session update listener 
 */
function sessionUpdateListener(isAlive) {
  var message = isAlive ? 'Session Updated' : 'Session Removed';
  message += ': ' + session.sessionId;
  appendMessage(message);
  if (!isAlive) {
    session = null;
  }
};

/**
 * receiver listener during initialization
 */
function receiverListener(e) {
  if( e === 'available' ) {
    console.log("receiver found");
    appendMessage("receiver found");
  }
  else {
    console.log("receiver list empty");
    appendMessage("receiver list empty");
  }
}

/**
 * select a media URL 
 * @param {string} m An index for media URL
 */
function selectMedia(m) {
  console.log("media selected" + m);
  appendMessage("media selected" + m);
  currentMediaURL = mediaURLs[m]; 
  var playpauseresume = document.getElementById("playpauseresume");
  document.getElementById('thumb').src = mediaThumbs[m];
}

/**
 * launch app and request session
 */
function launchApp() {
  console.log("launching app...");
  appendMessage("launching app...");
  chrome.cast.requestSession(onRequestSessionSuccess, onLaunchError);
}

/**
 * callback on success for requestSession call  
 * @param {Object} e A non-null new session.
 */
function onRequestSessionSuccess(e) {
  console.log("session success: " + e.sessionId);
  appendMessage("session success: " + e.sessionId);
  session = e;
  document.getElementById("casticon").src = 'images/cast_icon_active.png'; 
}

/**
 * callback on launch error
 */
function onLaunchError() {
  console.log("launch error");
  appendMessage("launch error");
}

/**
 * stop app/session
 */
function stopApp() {
  session.stop(onStopAppSuccess, onError);
}

/**
 * load media
 * @param {string} i An index for media
 */
function loadMedia(i) {
  if (!session) {
    console.log("no session");
    appendMessage("no session");
    return;
  }
  console.log("loading..." + currentMediaURL);
  appendMessage("loading..." + currentMediaURL);
  var mediaInfo = new chrome.cast.media.MediaInfo(currentMediaURL);
  mediaInfo.contentType = 'application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml';
  var request = new chrome.cast.media.LoadRequest(mediaInfo);
  request.autoplay = false;
  request.currentTime = 0;

  var payload = {
    "title:" : mediaTitles[i],
    "thumb" : mediaThumbs[i]
  };

  var json = {
    "payload" : payload
  };

  request.customData = json;

  session.loadMedia(request,
    onMediaDiscovered.bind(this, 'loadMedia'),
    onMediaError);

}

/**
 * callback on success for loading media
 * @param {Object} e A non-null media object
 */
function onMediaDiscovered(how, mediaSession) {
  console.log("new media session ID:" + mediaSession.mediaSessionId);
  appendMessage("new media session ID:" + mediaSession.mediaSessionId + ' (' + how + ')');
  currentMediaSession = mediaSession;
  mediaSession.addUpdateListener(onMediaStatusUpdate);
  mediaCurrentTime = currentMediaSession.currentTime;
  playpauseresume.innerHTML = 'Play';
  document.getElementById("casticon").src = 'images/cast_icon_active.png'; 
}

/**
 * callback on media loading error
 * @param {Object} e A non-null media object
 */
function onMediaError(e) {
  console.log("media error");
  appendMessage("media error");
  document.getElementById("casticon").src = 'images/cast_icon_warning.png'; 
}

/**
 * callback for media status event
 * @param {Object} e A non-null media object
 */
function onMediaStatusUpdate(isAlive) {
  if( progressFlag ) {
    document.getElementById("progress").value = parseInt(100 * currentMediaSession.currentTime / currentMediaSession.media.duration);
  }
  document.getElementById("playerstate").innerHTML = currentMediaSession.playerState;
}

/**
 * play media
 */
function playMedia() {
  if( !currentMediaSession ) 
    return;

  var playpauseresume = document.getElementById("playpauseresume");
  if( playpauseresume.innerHTML == 'Play' ) {
    currentMediaSession.play(null,
      mediaCommandSuccessCallback.bind(this,"playing started for " + currentMediaSession.sessionId),
      onError);
      playpauseresume.innerHTML = 'Pause';
      //currentMediaSession.addListener(onMediaStatusUpdate);
      appendMessage("play started");
  }
  else {
    if( playpauseresume.innerHTML == 'Pause' ) {
      currentMediaSession.pause(null,
        mediaCommandSuccessCallback.bind(this,"paused " + currentMediaSession.sessionId),
        onError);
      playpauseresume.innerHTML = 'Resume';
      appendMessage("paused");
    }
    else {
      if( playpauseresume.innerHTML == 'Resume' ) {
        currentMediaSession.play(null,
          mediaCommandSuccessCallback.bind(this,"resumed " + currentMediaSession.sessionId),
          onError);
        playpauseresume.innerHTML = 'Pause';
        appendMessage("resumed");
      }
    }
  }
}

/**
 * stop media
 */
function stopMedia() {
  if( !currentMediaSession ) 
    return;

  currentMediaSession.stop(null,
    mediaCommandSuccessCallback.bind(this,"stopped " + currentMediaSession.sessionId),
    onError);
  var playpauseresume = document.getElementById("playpauseresume");
  playpauseresume.innerHTML = 'Play';
  appendMessage("media stopped");
}

/**
 * set media volume
 * @param {Number} level A number for volume level
 * @param {Boolean} mute A true/false for mute/unmute 
 */
function setMediaVolume(level, mute) {
  if( !currentMediaSession ) 
    return;

  var volume = new chrome.cast.Volume();
  volume.level = level;
  currentVolume = volume.level;
  volume.muted = mute;
  var request = new chrome.cast.media.VolumeRequest();
  request.volume = volume;
  currentMediaSession.setVolume(request,
    mediaCommandSuccessCallback.bind(this, 'media set-volume done'),
    onError);
}

/**
 * mute media
 * @param {DOM Object} cb A checkbox element
 */
function muteMedia(cb) {
  if( cb.checked == true ) {
    document.getElementById('muteText').innerHTML = 'Unmute media';
    setMediaVolume(currentVolume, true);
    appendMessage("media muted");
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById('muteText').innerHTML = 'Mute media';
    setMediaVolume(currentVolume, false);
    appendMessage("media unmuted");
  } 
}

/**
 * seek media position
 * @param {Number} pos A number to indicate percent
 */
function seekMedia(pos) {
  console.log('Seeking ' + currentMediaSession.sessionId + ':' +
    currentMediaSession.mediaSessionId + ' to ' + pos + "%");
  progressFlag = 0;
  var request = new chrome.cast.media.SeekRequest();
  request.currentTime = pos * currentMediaSession.media.duration / 100;
  currentMediaSession.seek(request,
    onSeekSuccess.bind(this, 'media seek done'),
    onError);
}

/**
 * callback on success for media commands
 * @param {string} info A message string
 * @param {Object} e A non-null media object
 */
function onSeekSuccess(info) {
  console.log(info);
  appendMessage(info);
  setTimeout(function(){progressFlag = 1},1500);
}

/**
 * callback on success for media commands
 * @param {string} info A message string
 * @param {Object} e A non-null media object
 */
function mediaCommandSuccessCallback(info) {
  console.log(info);
  appendMessage(info);
}


/**
 * append message to debug message window
 * @param {string} message A message string
 */
function appendMessage(message) {
  var dw = document.getElementById("debugmessage");
  dw.innerHTML += '\n' + JSON.stringify(message);
};
```

I am trying media #1 which is .ism - I also tried with the /Manifest - but no luck.
In the debugging console I am getting:

```
[214.054s] [cast.player.api.Player] load -3
 media_player.js:23
 [214.060s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Opening Xhr [GET http://playready.directtaps.net/smoothstreaming/TTLSS720VC1/To_The_Limit_720.ism/Manifest -1]
 media_player.js:23
 [214.065s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Will abort after 10000ms if incomplete, xhr2 false [GET http://playready.directtaps.net/smoothstreaming/TTLSS720VC1/To_The_Limit_720.ism/Manifest -1]
 media_player.js:23
 [214.070s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Sending request [GET http://playready.directtaps.net/smoothstreaming/TTLSS720VC1/To_The_Limit_720.ism/Manifest -1]
 media_player.js:23
 [214.088s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Request complete [GET http://playready.directtaps.net/smoothstreaming/TTLSS720VC1/To_The_Limit_720.ism/Manifest 200]
 media_player.js:23
 [214.120s] [cast.player.api.Player] sourceopen
 media_player.js:23
 [214.142s] [cast.player.api.Player] play
 media_player.js:23
 [214.291s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Load metadata error
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [214.296s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Resetting media element
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [214.303s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Sending error message to 4:client-34217
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [214.307s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"4:client-34217","data":"{\"requestId\":9217017,\"type\":\"LOAD_FAILED\"}"}
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [214.171s] [cast.player.api.Player] error
 media_player.js:23
Fatal Error - 1 index.html:61
 [214.176s] [cast.player.api.Player] unload -3
```

Any idea???

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you find that URL?  It's incomplete, the right one is **http://playready.directtaps.net/smoothstreaming/TTLSS720VC1/To_The_Limit_720.ism/manifest**, but it is unlikely to work. Other files have been posted at: [Microsoft's SmoothStreaming samples files](http://playready.directtaps.net/smoothstreaming/), that said, I don't believe that Microsoft is providing a CORS header that works for Chromecast.

We do provide some [very simple media](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/cast-media-server-samples/media.zip) that you can host yourself. And we provide a [very simple server](https://github.com/googlecast/cast-support-media-server), if you need that to host and provide a CORS header as well.

Comment: Thanks - I'll try it out! are there any examples for using Widevine & Playready?

Comment: I used the medias provided, but it will return media error. seems like my server is all ok, since when using the Styled Application with an MP4 it works. when I use the custom application with .m3u8 or .ism it will fail

Comment: There is smoothstreaming in the "very simple media' link above.

Comment: I know. But the reciever example won't consume it and return an error. also for m3u8 you provided in the sample... could it be that the receiver example for the Protocols is faulty?

Comment: I'll try to check this week.

Comment: Thanks. In addition - for the smoothstreaming, we should pass the receiver with the url of .ism/manifest right?

Comment: Hi Les, the problem was at my end with some router issues. both m3u8 and ism are working! However, could you please share some DRM code (widevine or playready) regarding such playback? Thanks!

Comment: If you don't need CustomData, and you put your License Server info into your Manifest, PlayReady should just work.  Widevine, I think is a bit trickier, Sean should be posting some sample code shortly.

Comment: Thanks again. I do need PlayReady CustomData... should I just set it before acquiring the license?

Comment: Hi @Les, any news about example of PlayReady/Widevine?

Comment: Yes - set before License acquisition.